# Why is pytorch slower on m1 pro 10 core vs linux CPU?

Tags: linux, pytorch, profiling, apple-m1

I ran the following benchmark from [here](https://pytorch.org/tutorials/recipes/recipes/benchmark.html) .

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

import torch


def batched_dot_mul_sum(a, b):
    '''Computes batched dot by multiplying and summing'''
    return a.mul(b).sum(-1)


def batched_dot_bmm(a, b):
    '''Computes batched dot by reducing to ``bmm``'''
    a = a.reshape(-1, 1, a.shape[-1])
    b = b.reshape(-1, b.shape[-1], 1)
    return torch.bmm(a, b).flatten(-3)


# Input for benchmarking
x = torch.randn(10000, 64)

# Ensure that both functions compute the same output
assert batched_dot_mul_sum(x, x).allclose(batched_dot_bmm(x, x))

import timeit

t0 = timeit.Timer(
    stmt='batched_dot_mul_sum(x, x)',
    setup='from __main__ import batched_dot_mul_sum',
    globals={'x': x})

t1 = timeit.Timer(
    stmt='batched_dot_bmm(x, x)',
    setup='from __main__ import batched_dot_bmm',
    globals={'x': x})

print(f'mul_sum(x, x):  {t0.timeit(100) / 100 * 1e6:>5.1f} us')
print(f'bmm(x, x):      {t1.timeit(100) / 100 * 1e6:>5.1f} us')
```

I got

```
mul_sum(x, x):  1065.9 us
bmm(x, x):      134.5 us
```

on mac

and

```
mul_sum(x, x):   52.3 us
bmm(x, x):      120.1 us
```

on linux CPU

I'm seeing a huge performance difference, is this expected?

I first noticed this difference on a more serious program, and am trying to replicate it here.

Comment: run `lscpu | grep architecture` so we know which "linux CPU" you are talking about at least. It is most likely x86 but could be ARM and other esoteric archs.

Comment: increase the input size (10000) times 10, 100 ... what are those results? Use x for one test and create another input y for the other.

Answer (score 1):

John Zavialov [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76831205/7458927) goes over the general issues, I'll briefly list them here. This portion is basically going to be summarizing that answer and get into how to speed it up.

1.Optimization Progress: PyTorch's adaptation to the Apple Silicon architecture is still undergoing refinement and is not as mature as Linux's setup.

Architecture-Specific Tuning: PyTorch is setup for specific Architectures, which means that it may not have as solid performance on each system.

Instruction Set Variation: The instruction set architecture significantly impacts the execution efficiency of various operations with ARM-based systems(M1 Pros) being distinct then x86_84 (Linux) which can lead to big differences in performance

In order to fix this or speed this up.  Mac has added new [Metal Performance Shader](https://developer.apple.com/metal/).  If you activate this for [Pytorch on Mac](https://developer.apple.com/metal/pytorch/) you should see a performance boost.  You can see installation instructions in the link, I put down a code example to test and activate it:

```
import torch
if torch.backends.mps.is_available():
    mps_device = torch.device("mps")
    x = torch.ones(1, device=mps_device)
    print (x)
else:
    print ("MPS device not found.")
```